# Countable dense subset of real line whose complement is not dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I would like a subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ which is both countable and dense but with $A^C$ to NOT be dense. I feel like this is impossible but am unsure how to show it (e.g. by contradiction might imply that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable). I want to use this as a lemma for something else but wanted to verify whether or not such a set even exists first.

Comment: That is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is countable and $X$ is a space in which every non-empty open set is uncountable (as $\Bbb R$ is: all open intervals / open balls have the same size as $\Bbb R$), then automatically $A^\complement$ is dense: if $O$ is non-empty open, by assumption $O \nsubseteq A$ (or $O$ would be countable as a subset of $A$) so $O \cap A^\complement \neq \emptyset$, which exactly says that $A^\complement$ is dense.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is countable $A^C$ must be dense.  Any interval has uncountably many points in it, and only countably many can be in $A$, so some (uncountably many) must be in $A^C$.  Given a point $x$, find a decreasing set of intervals around it, then choose an element of $A^C$ from each interval and you have a sequence converging to $x$.  This shows $A^C$ is dense.

Answer (score 0):

If $A^c$ is not dense then $A$ must contain an open set which is not countable.

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer another answer on why such examples do not exist:

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space, it is Baire. Hence any comeager set is dense. Now let $A$ be countable, then $A = \cup_{x \in A} \{x\}$. Since $\{x\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is nowhere dense for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $A$ is meager, hence $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is dense.